# Combine multiple BeautifulSoup calls

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to iterate over a webpage.
I use soup to find/select the tags in the html.
For now, I have the two separated statements. But I'd like to have it done in one statement so I dont have to iterate over the same page twice.
My code is the following:

```
headers = ({'User-Agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})

sapo="https://casa.sapo.pt/comprar-apartamentos/ofertas-recentes/distrito.lisboa/?pn=1"
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data1 = [json.loads(x.string) for x in soup.find_all("script", type="application/ld+json")]
data2= soup.select('div.property')
del  data1[:2]
```

There are 25 properties on the page. data1 returns 27 results, whereas the first 2 results are just overhead, so I delete them. So I have 25 results with 10 "columns".
Now I'd like to have the data2 as an 11th column.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Try with this lines of code.
`soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')` 
`data = [json.loads(x.string) for x in soup.find_all("script", type="application/ld+json")] + [x for x in soup.select('div.property')]`

Comment: see my comment further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you like to get the whole HTML element, but here we go. Change your strategy selecting elements and start withe the containers:

```
data = []

for e in soup.select('div.property'):
    d = {'html':e}
    d.update(json.loads(e.script.string))
    data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### EDIT

Based on your comment extract the href via

```
d = {'link':'https://casa.sapo.pt'+e.a.get('href')}
```

---

```
data = []

for e in soup.select('div.property'):
    d = {'link':'https://casa.sapo.pt'+e.a.get('href')}
    d.update(json.loads(e.script.string))
    data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: We're getting closer! Now the result's structure is correct but I don't want the whole HTML. I only want the 'div',class_="property" as it holds the URL to the real estate. Any idea?

Comment: The expected result should be part of your question next time, to clarify - Take look at the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try to be more precise next time. Your solution works like charm. Thank you!!